# Incorrect File Date and Date Modified Metadata

Tags: file, video, metadata

Videos I shoot using an [inexpensive pen camera](https://onzpuco.net/product/hidden-spy-camera-pen-nanny-camera-pen-hd-1080p-spy-kit-body-camera-portable-pocket-mini-camera-150-minutes-battery-life-with-32gb-sd-card) show an incorrect date in the Date and Date modified fields. When I view the file's Properties I see a Created date that is correct.

What might be causing this? Please see the images attached below.

The .MOV file (with a correct value in the Date modified field) was shot using an [inexpensive action camera](https://bestviewsreviews.com/sports-action-video-cameras/crosstour-sports-action-camera-4k-20mp-wifi-vlogging-camera-underwater-40m-with-remote-control-ip68-waterproof-case/). The .AVI file is the one shot by the pen camera.

[image: video files list]
[image: file properties view]

Comment: Are the clocks set properly on both?  IIRC, cameras such as the pen camera have the clocks set by creating a special text file on the card.  Additionally, the different cameras may set the timestamps in different ways.  For example, one may set all the timestamps at the time when the files are first created, while the second my set them to when the file is finally closed. It's highly unlikely that they are both using the same program to create the files, so differences are expected.

Comment: StarGeek: On this particular pen camera, the text file that I think you refer to seems to have the exclusive function of adding a timestamp to the video or photo. I'm not aware of it having any other function. I tried reformatting the micro SD card that came with the camera and -- after reinserting it back into the card slot -- the camera generated two folders and one text file (time.txt) which all had Date (and Date created, Date modified) fields with date values that were set one day and several hours before they were actually created.

Comment: @StarGeek's comment above gave me an idea which may have helped resolve the various file date fields displaying the incorrect date and time. I took the SD card out of the pen camera, reformatted it and then created the folders and file (PHOTO VIDEO time.txt) the pen camera would normally auto-create upon inserting the SD card into the camera. Now the video files display the correct dates; the times are off by a minute or so. Interestingly, somewhere in this process, the pen camera lost its ability to take photos. Since this is an inexpensive device, I suppose I get what I pay for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with feedback provided by [StarGeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3525475/stargeek) in a comment to my question, I reformatted the SD card that came with the pen camera, then created the two folders and one text file (PHOTO, VIDEO, time.txt) the pen camera would normally auto-create upon inserting the SD card into the camera. That seemed to resolve the issue with the various file date fields showing incorrect dates.

In one of my comments above I also complained that the fix seemed to disable the photo function; it turns out that I had just not understood the camera's instructions clearly (the user must invoke the video mode first, then use the function button to take photos).

I'm not going to mark this answer as the accepted one for now; I want to test the pen camera out for a few days to ensure that the fix described above actually continues to work.